Dimensionality reduction for total variation
Let $P_i,Q_i$, $i\in[n]$,
be distributions on a finite set $\Omega$.
We will use $P^\otimes_{i\in[n]}$ to denote $n$-fold products of distributions.
For each $i\in[n]$, define the
dimensionally-reduced pair
$\tilde P_i,\tilde Q_i$ as follows:
let $A_i=\{\omega\in\Omega: P_i(\omega)>Q_i(\omega)\}$
and define
$p_i:=P_i(A_i)$,
$q_i:=Q_i(A_i)$.
Then $\tilde P_i,\tilde Q_i$
are defined to be Bernoullis with parameters
$p_i$ and $q_i$, respectively.
By the data processing inequality, we have the obvious relation
$$
\|
P^\otimes_{i\in[n]}-Q^\otimes_{i\in[n]}
\|_1
\ge 
\|
\tilde P^\otimes_{i\in[n]}-
\tilde Q^\otimes_{i\in[n]}
\|_1
.
$$
We conjecture the following non-obvious relation:
$$
\|
P^\otimes_{i\in[n]}-Q^\otimes_{i\in[n]}
\|_1
\le 
2
\|
\tilde P^\otimes_{i\in[n]}-
\tilde Q^\otimes_{i\in[n]}
\|_1
.
$$

Are these not equal? Perhaps I am parsing your notation wrong, but see after Definition 2.6 of this. It is also worth mentioning your "dimensionality reduction" is often called "Scheffe's test", and is not optimal for dimensionality reduction in squared hellinger distance (this is the main result of the prior link).

Then are equal for $n=1$ but no longer equal for $|\Omega|=3$ and $n=2$.

Mark Schultz-Wu linked to the paper Communication-constrained hypothesis testing: Optimality, robustness, and reverse data processing inequalities by Ankit Pensia, Varun Jog, and Po-Ling Loh which turns out to contain the clue to a solution:
Fix a small parameter $\rho$. Let $\Omega$ have three elements and let $P$ for each $i$ put probability $\rho$ on the first element, $1/2-2\rho$ on the second, and $1/2+\rho$ on the third, while $Q$ for each $i$ puts probability $0$ on the first element, $1/2$ on the second, and $1/2$ on the third. Take $P_i= P$ for each $i$ and $Q_i=Q$ for each $i$. Then $\tilde{P}_i$ and $\tilde{Q}_i$ are Bernoulli with parameters $1/2+2\rho$ and $1/2$ respectively. Take $n = \rho^{-3/2}$. (This example is taken from Proposition 2.7 of the sample complexity of Scheffe's test on the non-optimality of Scheffe's test, and the point of this value of $n$ is that it is much smaller than the sample complexity $\approx \rho^{-2}$ of Scheffe's test but much larger than the sample complexity $\approx \rho^{-1}$ of the optimal test.)
The total variation distance between $P^{\otimes}_{i\in [n]}$ and $Q^{\otimes}_{i \in [n]}$ is at least the probabibility that the first element of $\Omega$ appears in one of the $n$ samples from $P$, since this can never happen for samples from $Q$. The probability of this is $1 - (1-\rho)^{ \rho^{-3/2}} \approx 1- e^{ - \rho^{-1/2}}$ and hence is very close to $1$.
On the other hand, $\tilde{Q}_{i\in [n]}^{\otimes}$ assigns probability $2^{-n}$ to each sample while $\tilde{P}_{i\in [n]}^{\otimes}$ assigns probability $(1/2+2\rho)^j (1/2-2\rho)^{n-j}$ to a sample with $j$ $1$s. The total variation distance is therefore $\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} \max ( 2^{-n} - (1/2+2\rho)^j (1/2-2\rho)^{n-j} ,0)$. We have $$(1/2+2\rho)^j (1/2-2\rho)^{n-j} = 2^{-n} (1 - 16 \rho^2)^{n/2}  \left( \frac{1/2+2\rho}{1/2-2\rho}\right)^{j-n/2}. $$
The factor $(1 - 16 \rho^2)^{n/2}  \approx e^{ - 8 n \rho^2 } =e^{-8n \rho^{1/2}}$ is $1-o(1)$ and the factor $\left( \frac{1/2+2\rho}{1/2-2\rho}\right)^{j-n/2} \approx e^{ 8 \rho (j-n/2)} $ is $1-o(1)$ as long as $|j-n/2| = o( \rho^{-1} ) = o( n^{2/3})$.
Hence the summand $ \binom{n}{j} \max ( 2^{-n} - (1/2+2\rho)^j (1/2-2\rho)^{n-j} ,0)$ is $\binom{n}{j} 2^{-n} o(1)$  as long as $|j-n/2|$ is $o(n^{2/3})$. Outside of that range, the summand is still at most $\binom{n}{j} 2^{-n}$ and the sum away from that range is $o(1)$ by the central limit theorem or standard large deviation estimates since $n^{2/3}$ is much smaller than $1$. In that range, the sum is at most $o(1)$.
So the total variation distance between $\tilde P^{\otimes}_{i\in [n]}$ and $\tilde Q^{\otimes}_{i \in [n]}$ is $o(1)$.
Taking $\rho$ sufficiently small, we violate the inequality.
The proof of the second part could probably be done more quickly using the Hellinger distance as in the linked paper.
